# CloudFlare - Show captcha to everyone, except country

Tags: cloudflare

I wonder whether it is possible in **CloudFlare's IP firewall** to **challenge everyone** with a captcha, **except 2-3 countries**.

Tried on my own and searched the web but did not find how.

Comment: Ask CloudFlare support, they're excellent.